# jquery datatable table tools export to excel is not showing me the table data in file

Tags: javascript, jquery, excel, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables

I want to export my table to in excel file using jquery datatable table tool it is showing me data on the table but when in first row it is saying no data available, when i search the data it says no data available and when i click on excel button then it does save the file but shows no data in the excel file.and also pagination and new in not working.I am also using bootstrap 3 in it
Here is my Jquery code

```js
$('#datatable_Vouchers').DataTable( {
    dom: 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
    tableTools: {
         "sSwfPath": "../assets/swf/copy_csv_xls.swf"
    }
});
```

and my tabletools file paths are

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/dataTables.tableTools.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css">
<script src="../assets/js/dataTables.tableTools.js'"></script>
<script src="../assets/js/dataTables.tableTools.min.js'>"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is case when your table row in dynamically appended.
Actually, datatable js code execute first and after that row appends. 
Datatable always saves the file when the table as it is in initial position and initially table has no rows, So, append your row before calling datatable jquery code.